# dc offset removal

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, circuit-design, adc, dc

I want to manipulate dc offset of a signal. By using a RC filter, I can delete the dc offset when the cap is charged but there is some problem like frequency issue and long time constant. Any circuit suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The English word *manipulate* implies only *altering*. It doesn't connote anything else. So none of us can have any clue what you mean to do with the DC offset. Only that you intend to do *something*. And yes, Ohms times Capacitance yields time and an RC implies a time constant based on their values. How can be suggest anything if we don't know what you want to do?

Comment: It'd be nice if you'd include a schematic of the circuit you're having problems with as well as a representation of the signal you're starting out with and of the output that you hope to derive from it.

Comment: A capacitor will remove DC offsets, a high pass filter will give a 'new' DC reference

Comment: @VoltageSpike well, how strictly are we speaking? Because honestly, from a signal processing point of view, no, a linear HPF must not give you a new DC reference. (and with a non-zero source impedance and with any finite sink impedance, a capacitor + load forms a HPF, too)

Comment: @MarcusMüller you could attach the resistor to 2.5V instead of 0V and give the signal a 2.5V shift (with only the AC content getting through)

Comment: Then it's no longer a linear filter! You're adding a new frequency component. Linear systems can't do that.

Comment: What is the signal, and why do you want to change its 'dc offset'? If you have a circuit this will be applied to, please show it to us.

Comment: You can do this with an op-amp and preserve bandwidth from DC to VHF or maybe even UHF (depending on the op-amp).

Comment: Adding or removing DC offsets while maintaining frequency response down to DC is a somewhat common thing. Please don't be overly pedantic about it. This is a general comment to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your incoming signal has a known, constant DC offset, it can be removed or controlled by using a differential amplifier and changing the (-) input with an added voltage ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmM0EE4DMGAcB2ZLMSANjABYxkQFJaQKtaBTAWjDAChlJ8UK9ZAlIpIuFCMYgAkgDkefRqQoD6FDKOSDpAeQCqAFS4B3cBhqVVYC%20HyjIplIXAVrtq1CfIXNmj8s3LwAnZ0tbLARwmnoSeC4AQ3NosOSQCTAkDiQ4%20CFoDQwMfDo4bSLi1WR0cDzHMzcJbXUVNS8zaibxNN4JRwAlcGo7UU5A1Xp1eiRJqHQuAHMh-x0xyQcvMHxrYa3R4ebwMXg5pH6WAGcASwuAFwSAOwBjFidIlPeUbXbGCiadJgrSZORppUGHeqMLApUF%20EIgT5wwFpWJ5N5RdYI3iYyGHYRaHQBH74zF4qSOJbQ%20hUrHUrAbRyhGkkmk01HxUIklnYknsuCLNrMnRYelQLwAN0FPMJLlijHySGqM1OiQRGMOyMOGSymVqdTmpFwpEImGIpFI%20OhBqN%20Eo5pUxBsOD18QA9mLWrFIlsIDNYPBiqQRMIxdx3RBPeBvbaGDA8oHgzlwFwgA)):

[image]

You could also AC couple the signal. As you noted, the problem with AC coupling is that the AC-coupled signal could have a very long time constant. There's another issue as well: a running DC imbalance in your signal will add an offset to the resulting output.

To deal with both issues, what you can do is detect the positive and negative peaks of the signal and use that to compute the midpoint, then feed that back to cancel the offset.

Here's an analog-approach example using peak detectors ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0mRA2aAWArHSBOAzJByAOVVAdgJHQpGWwoFMBaMMAKACZITr8Q3lJqmBL37UQAeQCqAFRYB3aoREDkPPgMjyQ2VG3CY9OvWz5QtyJeurZjozQovkwBxeSv3re53sf69mgCdtXT9PUIEwDA8jXlRhGwE2OLMFKyThKwSU2IzktOTNAHNtDhKBLOxsYQ0WIKz0ssaIqNqctvqC8BaANxACctL%20tsTqROhUKEmYdAQWAENg2xUbZT7wCaYJyKiI6GxkTEwSVDATmgRSBCc99B27yFptjC184SGGzQWq8mQwYV9fm91iBNl0drxoCQwCRsAQwMhjpBUNgDBM2NAEIcsdiiCRMGDngATVzUP6Cf5krwAOV%20hBYAGNyaT-kJuMgprAMBB0VCYXCEehkaioJzWMUDv8eBLqEMaqlRPVRDR-C8lSs2CQfCtoldRuUQvw5Ys9cbvtkYmbLbrArxNWEYsrJk8deQzdKzR53brpYDzd6Vg7tSxig7WTETv4zBwuFdXSFY412QAFaBJgDSWkuzKZvo8WdQLmlBZV0ZACd05ATPpAVNTGYUZoQkDjeib5E9rNQFiZxb95C77KL3eiIQH2l1Y5Heiz4eHWjNM9HJGqwaZ%20BUrIu1TMjKLhc3dhFUQgDHRbAIUIIqLYYGwkQI7dFLGJe58Sl71NpBHm4-7hffLhOBspwEhgIJnheYBXkkN53s2biQvccCnCYwjOp8FCFnAZZ2oaawgaC6FjLyOg0PAJxYNykLQrC8KIkKSSgXmLiwuyM4EOyebLtoHEUNxMRcfE8YPsaHgJjEVbYWJIl4QguFSVo5bcXJ07cdJ-bnmWIlZoJFCaeWmkYb2WYqXxQIESBRHgdA55QggCCwpAqiagQOjWbZUHXre95ODsmbcRWZkUE22T5iFxkhR4Vhtqsjo2jEzBal4YCRhwzzFBqXguJlvDNlMLC9EMMRFaUGijCKaVIce7Ycqgq5FSERXWlGnB9IkySWB1IAAJJUq0OUxRJeXNM8qR2jF0XDa0Wa%20jNspMZmhZkjNZJFEFhACDNrI1MUJnJCZdo1EE%20YuHt27oYt06nQFLjxSE8KDisD2TJVU7gClxrPW9z0JbdikydhML-ApChAyaYNfVoEPdo6kMOE9H3Lk4H0eEj716GjOlQxOynaWpLAAPZltyTo6NCEATDAURHFujERITL2kycUJUFTGA03EjEQKwsKYZMp7jBCEzdQAdgADgArgALgAOgAzgAIgAwvLBMAGZq3LdBSywvO3lQgwCAr0sAJ7y0rJv0gANnQLBAA))

[image]

If your system is ultimately digitizing the input, you could use this path to calculate the midpoint (your battery DC voltage) then feed that back to the front-end using a DAC to cancel the offset and allow you to pull out the AC signal.

Answer (score 3):

> By using a RC filter, I can delete the dc offset when the cap is charged but there is some problem like frequency issue and long time constant.

Well, you want a high-pass filter: you want to delete exactly one frequency in your signal, 0 Hz.

Now, in reality, no real-world system that doesn't have infinite delay can ever delete a single frequency, so there's no way around the "time constant" issue: the "sharper" the filtering, the longer the time constant; that's math (it's the same math that underlies Heisenberg's uncertainty principle: The Fourier transform just doesn't allow you to have something that's both very sharp in frequency and very short in time; it's mathematically impossible).

So, your problem can't really be solved completely. Of course, there's always worse solutions, and we don't know whether you selected your RC in the best of your interests, or whether the frequency response of an RC filter is good enough for your signal of interest – we don't know that signal!

So, what you need to do is actually sit down, and write a signal specification for yourself. What is the lowest frequency you still need? No use making any filter that cuts off below that, that frequency is good enough. What's the ripple in gain of your signal you can accept for the signal that in your passband? What's the suppression that you need for your DC component? Is a factor of 100 enough? 1000? 100 000? 10 000 000?

After you have that (and not before) you sit down and pick a filter design (e.g. RC, Sallen-Key, some more advanced stuff). Often, you'll find yourself in need for a first stage of buffering. Often "AC-coupling" a buffer, which has a very high input impedance, is enough to solve your issue. But this really depends on what your signal is (how strongly it's driven).

Comment: First I'd like to thank you for your detailed response. My signal is a battery voltage containing both AC and DC components. Ac multisine 20mV(P-P) signal from 0 to 5kHz with DC amplitude of around 1V .the problem is that with RC filter I'm not able to collect the data regarding below 1Hz. 
The capacitor introduces a frequency-dependent phase shift, which is difficult to compensate due to the non-linear behavior of a practical capacitor. This effect can be diminished by increasing the size of the capacitor. However, this makes the settling time of the measurement system very large.

Comment: well, what *is* the lowest frequency relevant to your measurement? It's not 0Hz, because that would include the DC offset (which you explicitly do not want). As explained in my answer, this is the *first thing you actually need to answer*. With a concrete number. Suppression down to 0 Hz is physically and mathematically impossible, but you can come close, at the cost of delay and effort. But we don't know how close you can get, so we can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: Yes of course. I will be glad to have for example 0.2 Hz.

Comment: Which filter design do you suggest for this? Even data of 0.5 Hz will do just fine.

Comment: that's a factor of 2.5, so there's worlds between these two numbers. So, no, "will be just fine" is not what you're looking for. You're looking for a definite lowest frequency that you need with an attenuation of less than 0.5; then you have the first *specification* for your filter!

Answer (score 2):

I’m a little confused by the question and

> I want to manipulate dc offset of a signal.

which suggests that you may be looking to change the DC level of the output.

I’m not at my desk right now to give a full discussion, but here’s something that I drew up on my phone that may work for you:

[image: dc level shifter]

Use the resistor that I highlighted as a potentiometer (or whatever)to tweak the DC level. Adjust the input AC coupling capacitor to suit your frequency. And tweak the gain as you see fit.

It’s basically a difference amp with the DC offset as your reference point.